# How to display two lists from two tables in single view in Android

Tags: android

[The Notepad example on android developer](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html) is good for a single list, but I want two lists drawing from two tables in a single view. Can anyone expand on how to implement something like this?

I'm wondering about how many adapters I'll need. Can I manage two lists in a single ListActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not implement as a [Relative Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) instead of the Linear Layout in the tutorial.  A linear layout only allows objects to be above and below each other while Relative Layout allows for more freedom.

Use

```
android:layout_toRightOf = ""
android:layout_toLeftOf = ""
```

To put things next to each other.
Mess with padding and spacing to get a good effect
(note using both at the same time causes a crash so be sure to just use one).

Also there is

```
android:layout_alignLeft
android:layout_alignRight
```

but I'm just in the process of working it out.

And here we are why not have some example code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id = "@+id/layout">



<TextView
android:id = "@+id/RightFrame"  
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:text="hello right frame"
android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"/>




<TextView
android:id = "@+id/LeftFrame"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:text="hello left frame"
android:layout_alignParentLeft = "true"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Sorry if its a little messy

EDIT:

About the list adapters I would think it would be best that you use two adapters and implement them in separate frame views or something. It may also be worth looking into [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) but they are horrible if you ask me.

Comment: Sorry, my question was vague. I've added more details.

Comment: @Ken Smith There we go I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, Jack. I'll look into them, but being an Android newb, it's probably a little over my head.

Comment: @Ken Smith just follow the example code and I'm sure you'll be fine =P